# Select one radio button from a row and get the values of other input field from that row

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

The following code displays rows of radio buttons along with other input fields. My problem is, how to get the values of other input field when one radio button is selected. I am using Code Igniter.

Here, is the view.

```
<table class="table table-hover">
<tr><th>Time</th><th>Fare</th><th>Seats Available</th><th>Seats Required</th></tr>
<?
   $slno = 0;
   foreach ($cab_schedule->result() as $row)
   {
       if($row->current_seat_available == 0) {
?>
<? //=$row->car_schedule_id?>
<tr>
<td>
    <input type="radio" name="slno_<?=$slno?>" id="slno_<?=$slno?>" value="<?=$row->journey_time?>
    &nbsp;<?=$row->datetime_ampm?>" disabled="true">&nbsp;<?=$row->journey_time?>&nbsp;<?=$row->datetime_ampm?>
</td>
<td>
    <input type="text" name="fare_" value="<?=$row->fare?>" readonly="true"><?=$row->fare?>
</td>
<td>
    <?=$row->current_seat_available?> No(s).
</td>
<td>
    Not Applicable
</td>
</tr> 
<? } else { ?>
<tr>
<td>
    <input type="radio" name="slno_<?=$slno?>" id="slno_<?=$slno?>" value="<?=$row->journey_time?>&nbsp;<?=$row->datetime_ampm?>" />
    &nbsp;<?=$row->journey_time?>&nbsp;<?=$row->datetime_ampm?>
</td>
<td>
    <input type="text" name="fare_<?=$slno?>" id="fare_<?=$slno?>" value="<?=$row->fare?>" readonly="true">
</td>
<td>
    <?=$row->current_seat_available?> No(s).
</td>
<td>
    <select name = "seat_required_<?=$slno?>" id="seat_required_<?=$slno?>" >
    <? for($i=1; $i<=$row->current_seat_available; $i++ ) { ?>
        <option value = "<?=$i?>"><?=$i?></option>
    <? } ?>    
    </select>
</td>
</tr>                       
<? } ?>                    
<? $slno++; } ?>
<input type="hidden" name="total_schedule" id="total_schedule" value="<?=$slno?>">
</table>
```

Here is the controller code.

$total_schedule = trim($this->security->xss_clean($_POST['total_schedule']));

```
        for($x=0 ; $x<$total_schedule; $x++) {
            if($_POST['slno_'.$x]) {
            $schedule_time = $_POST['slno_'.$x];
            $fare = $_POST['fare_'.$x];
            $required_seat  =   $_POST['seat_required_'.$x];
           }
        }
```

Please, help.

Comment: Are you tring to retrieve the value of an input box when one of the radio button is clicked? If so, you will need to do some JavaScript manipulation on the front end

Comment: ok, Could u pls help me. How to do that.

Comment: My task is, when i select one radio button than i should get the corresponding "fare" and "seat_required" as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
    var textValue = $('#textbox_id').val();
    var dropdownValue = $('#dropdown_id').val();

    // now make an ajax call to use this data
});
```

Comment: I have another issue. when one radio button is selected other buttons should be deselected. But, they all get selected when i chick on them.

Comment: $('chkbox_id').attr('checked', false); use this to uncheck any checkbox.